# Laravel Custom Login : Use MD5 hasing

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent, md5

I'm working on a Laravel project to use along with my old site currently holds many users which has a md5 hash attached to them, as the password. When i tried the login using the code below it returns false

```
Auth::attempt(['Email' => $request->get('Email'), 'Password' =>md5($password)])
```

1. Is there any way to use only MD5 hashing for Laravel custom login /change default hashing method to md5 ?

The user table have user_id as primary key so

2.How to get `user_id` of logined user when `Auth::id()` is called ?

Comment: Don't use md5 for password hashing. Even [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) warns against it: _"Warning
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm."_ Laravel already has a secure way of handling authentication so why struggle to make it insecure?

Comment: I personally don't even want to use md5 but the problem is that the project uses the tables from another project which is already been using the md5 for hashing so the only way to authenticate user is to use the md5 in Laravel also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already considered the fact that the MD5 is not recommended and you have no other choices, then you can follow these steps:

**Your 1st question:**

Check the user's password with MD5 method and find the user with a match:

```
$user = User::where('Email', $request->get('Email'))->where('Password', md5($password))->first();
```

Authenticate the user instance if they exist:

```
if($user) Auth::login($user);
```

The user will be authenticated directly with `Auth::login($user);` and no need to use Laravel standard authentication method `Auth::attempt($credentials);` in your case.

**2nd question:**

Add this to the User model to override the primary key:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

Hope it helps your situation.